# Android: OpenGL drawing only on one quarter of screen on Exynos devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, draw, viewport

**Problem.**
I have a problem with specific android devices. I'm using native C++ library to draw stuff in my app. For a long time the solution I use worked well on different devices, until I received a negative feedback from Samsung Galaxy S4 user (GT-I9500, Android 4.4.2, Exynos 5410). The result of my OpenGL drawing was corrupted. The texture that usually draw fullscreen in this case was shrinked to a quarter of the screen space and aligned to upper right corner. The background drawn with glClearColor was filling full screen tho.
 I was able to check on three other S4s - out of total four phones my app the drawing is corrupted only on Exynos devices. The other two had Snapdragon and there were no problems on them.

**Code.**
I've simmplified the code a bit so I can show it here. The task is basic: draw red background and black fullscreen rectangle on top of it. 

Below you can see my drawing method. Data I pass to the shaders don't affect anything in this simplified case.

```
// Use program
glUseProgram(_shaderProgram);
ERROR_STATUS
//bind quad mesh buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ibo);
ERROR_STATUS

//set attribs
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void *) (2 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
ERROR_STATUS

// Clear background to red
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);

glUniform2fv(_scaleUniform, 1, _eyes[0].scale.data);
glUniform1f(_offsetUniform, _eyes[0].offset);
glUniform1f(_offsetYUniform, _eyes[0].offsetY);

BindTextures(TEX);

// Draw
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
ERROR_STATUS

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
ERROR_STATUS
```

And here is my ConfigChooser([grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) was great help here).

```
private static class ConfigChooser implements GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser {

    public ConfigChooser(int r, int g, int b, int a, int depth, int stencil) {
        mRedSize = r;
        mGreenSize = g;
        mBlueSize = b;
        mAlphaSize = a;
        mDepthSize = depth;
        mStencilSize = stencil;
    }

    /* This EGL config specification is used to specify 2.0 rendering.
     * We use a minimum size of 4 bits for red/green/blue, but will
     * perform actual matching in chooseConfig() below.
     */
    private static int EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT = 4;
    private static int[] s_configAttribs2 =
    {
        EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 4,
        EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 4,
        EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 4,
        EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL10.EGL_NONE
    };

    public EGLConfig chooseConfig(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display) {

        /* Get the number of minimally matching EGL configurations
         */
        int[] num_config = new int[1];
        egl.eglChooseConfig(display, s_configAttribs2, null, 0, num_config);

        int numConfigs = num_config[0];

        if (numConfigs <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No configs match configSpec");
        }

        /* Allocate then read the array of minimally matching EGL configs
         */
        EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[numConfigs];
        egl.eglChooseConfig(display, s_configAttribs2, configs, numConfigs, num_config);

        if (DEBUG) {
             printConfigs(egl, display, configs);
        }
        /* Now return the "best" one
         */
        return chooseConfig(egl, display, configs);
    }

    public EGLConfig chooseConfig(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display,
            EGLConfig[] configs) {
        for(EGLConfig config : configs) {
            int d = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                    EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0);
            int s = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                    EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 0);

            // We need at least mDepthSize and mStencilSize bits
            if (d < mDepthSize || s < mStencilSize)
                continue;

            // We want an *exact* match for red/green/blue/alpha
            int r = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                    EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 0);
            int g = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                        EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 0);
            int b = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                        EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 0);
            int a = findConfigAttrib(egl, display, config,
                    EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 0);

            if (r == mRedSize && g == mGreenSize && b == mBlueSize && a == mAlphaSize)
                return config;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private int findConfigAttrib(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display,
            EGLConfig config, int attribute, int defaultValue) {

        if (egl.eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, attribute, mValue)) {
            return mValue[0];
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }

    private void printConfigs(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display,
        EGLConfig[] configs) {
        int numConfigs = configs.length;
        Log.w(TAG, String.format("%d configurations", numConfigs));
        for (int i = 0; i < numConfigs; i++) {
            Log.w(TAG, String.format("Configuration %d:\n", i));
            printConfig(egl, display, configs[i]);
        }
    }

    private void printConfig(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display,
            EGLConfig config) {
        int[] attributes = {
                EGL10.EGL_BUFFER_SIZE,
                EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE,
                EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE,
                EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE,
                EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE,
                EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE,
                EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE,
                EGL10.EGL_CONFIG_CAVEAT,
                EGL10.EGL_CONFIG_ID,
                EGL10.EGL_LEVEL,
                EGL10.EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT,
                EGL10.EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_PIXELS,
                EGL10.EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_WIDTH,
                EGL10.EGL_NATIVE_RENDERABLE,
                EGL10.EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID,
                EGL10.EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_TYPE,
                0x3030, // EGL10.EGL_PRESERVED_RESOURCES,
                EGL10.EGL_SAMPLES,
                EGL10.EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS,
                EGL10.EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,
                EGL10.EGL_TRANSPARENT_TYPE,
                EGL10.EGL_TRANSPARENT_RED_VALUE,
                EGL10.EGL_TRANSPARENT_GREEN_VALUE,
                EGL10.EGL_TRANSPARENT_BLUE_VALUE,
                0x3039, // EGL10.EGL_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGB,
                0x303A, // EGL10.EGL_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGBA,
                0x303B, // EGL10.EGL_MIN_SWAP_INTERVAL,
                0x303C, // EGL10.EGL_MAX_SWAP_INTERVAL,
                EGL10.EGL_LUMINANCE_SIZE,
                EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_MASK_SIZE,
                EGL10.EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE,
                EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE,
                0x3042 // EGL10.EGL_CONFORMANT
        };
        String[] names = {
                "EGL_BUFFER_SIZE",
                "EGL_ALPHA_SIZE",
                "EGL_BLUE_SIZE",
                "EGL_GREEN_SIZE",
                "EGL_RED_SIZE",
                "EGL_DEPTH_SIZE",
                "EGL_STENCIL_SIZE",
                "EGL_CONFIG_CAVEAT",
                "EGL_CONFIG_ID",
                "EGL_LEVEL",
                "EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT",
                "EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_PIXELS",
                "EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_WIDTH",
                "EGL_NATIVE_RENDERABLE",
                "EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID",
                "EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_TYPE",
                "EGL_PRESERVED_RESOURCES",
                "EGL_SAMPLES",
                "EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS",
                "EGL_SURFACE_TYPE",
                "EGL_TRANSPARENT_TYPE",
                "EGL_TRANSPARENT_RED_VALUE",
                "EGL_TRANSPARENT_GREEN_VALUE",
                "EGL_TRANSPARENT_BLUE_VALUE",
                "EGL_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGB",
                "EGL_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGBA",
                "EGL_MIN_SWAP_INTERVAL",
                "EGL_MAX_SWAP_INTERVAL",
                "EGL_LUMINANCE_SIZE",
                "EGL_ALPHA_MASK_SIZE",
                "EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE",
                "EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE",
                "EGL_CONFORMANT"
        };
        int[] value = new int[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
            int attribute = attributes[i];
            String name = names[i];
            if ( egl.eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, attribute, value)) {
                Log.w(TAG, String.format("  %s: %d\n", name, value[0]));
            } else {
                // Log.w(TAG, String.format("  %s: failed\n", name));
                while (egl.eglGetError() != EGL10.EGL_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
    }

    // Subclasses can adjust these values:
    protected int mRedSize;
    protected int mGreenSize;
    protected int mBlueSize;
    protected int mAlphaSize;
    protected int mDepthSize;
    protected int mStencilSize;
    private int[] mValue = new int[1];
}
```

I attach it with `setEGLConfigChooser(new ConfigChooser(5, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0))`.
Context factory:

```
    private static class ContextFactory implements GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory {
    private static int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;
    public EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        Log.w(TAG, "creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context");
        checkEglError("Before eglCreateContext", egl);
        int[] attrib_list = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
        EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);
        checkEglError("After eglCreateContext", egl);
        return context;
    }

    public void destroyContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLContext context) {
        egl.eglDestroyContext(display, context);
    }
}
```

I can provide other parts of my code if necessary.
 
**Results.**
While the usual, valid result is just black screen (the black, empty texture is overlapping the red background), on S4 Exynos the screen looks like this (the arrow on the right is just system button):

[image]

So here is the question. How to fix the problem, so the app is displaying the same thing different devices?

Comment: @RawN Done. The c++ tag has been suggested, that's why I picked it.

Comment: Could be a number of things, probably in code not shown here. For example, are you making sure that the vertex attributes are really at location 0 and 1?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thanks! That was was the issue - storing location of the attributes and using them insted of the fixed ones helped. Sorry for delayed response, I was unable to check it until today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my code thanks to RetoKoradi suggestion.
 The problem was that I've used fixed locations of uniforms in shaders (0 and 1). I'm not sure why this worked on most of deviced and on some not tho.

So instead of calls like:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

I'm now using:

```
_posAttribLocation = glGetAttribLocation(_shaderProgram, "a_position");
```

to store location of uniform after shader program is ready and using it instead of fixed one:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(_posAttribLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_posAttribLocation);
```